# What is [python-list] good for?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

The tag [python-list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-list) can be replaced by [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) + [list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/list) (or one of the more specific Python version tags).

[python-list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-list) has no description and only 18 questions (with 2 followers) - I really do not see any sense to keep it around.

Could we get rid of it by retagging [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) + [list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/list) and someone deleting the [python-list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-list)?

---

I am aware it's less then 50, so the [burniate-process](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination) has not to be followed, but I am inexperienced with tag creation/editing/deletion, so asking here.

Comment: [33,978 questions tagged \[python\] \[list\]](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+%5Blist%5D+is%3Aq)

Comment: I was making a point for your case. The point being that there is already a strong tendency to use [python]+[list].

Comment: Absolutely not needed. I’ve cleaned it up

Comment: Pretty curious how this happened.  Looks like the tag was added to a question two years ago.  Nothing, nothing, nothing and then bam!, 14 questions in the past month.  Did they change lists in Python recently?  Seems unlikely, maybe just people in same the company or school.  How's *that* for a good conspiracy theory.  It can always be made more interesting :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[python-list] is good for nothing and gone for good after Martijn Pieters deleted the tag.