# Re-tag or remove [rect]

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request, retag-request

While reading the burnination request for [ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ratio) I found myself on in the [rect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rect) tag. The tag wiki says that the tag is:

> To be used with RECT structure when using winapi

but every question on the first page seems to be using it to talk about "rectangles". It seems like after the burnination of [rectangle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rectangle) (See here: [Unify [triangle] [rectangle] [shape] [circle] and the like under [geometry]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254937/unify-triangle-rectangle-shape-circle-and-the-like-under-geometry)) people are just going to the closest remaining tag.

I have no connection to RECT, but if there is value to having a tag for the RECT structure in winapi think it would help reduce mistagged posts if the tag was renamed with something less generic sounding like [winapi-rect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/winapi-rect).

Otherwise, I argue it should be burninated (along with [rectangles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rectangles)) or retagged to [geometry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/geometry) as suggested here: [Unify [triangle] [rectangle] [shape] [circle] and the like under [geometry]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254937/unify-triangle-rectangle-shape-circle-and-the-like-under-geometry).

Comment: Good idea, then [next year somebody else can propose we change it back](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/376784/what-is-python-list-good-for). Keep everyone busy.

Comment: @JoshCaswell why can't we have one tag for everything... #TAG #ALL #TEH #THINGS

Comment: The tag's clearly about rectangles. While it's kinda silly it's no pitfall and nobody's going to add this tag accidentally with a different meaning. I just can't care about this one.